# Beamer - generate some slides separately, include them in the main file

Tags: beamer, include

I have a few slides that have `\animategraphics` in them (as a way to embed GIFs consisting of hundreds of frames). Generating those particular slides takes a long time, and it's not really necessary if I change other, more lightweight slides (I use `make` to track dependencies between files, so things are rebuilt on demand).

I would like to build those slides only if I update the GIFs, somehow including them into the main presentation file. Problem is, I don't really know how to approach this. I've heard of `\include`, but I've never really had a LaTeX document built from multiple source files, so I'm unsure if these `\include`d files are supposed to contain the preamble, if the sections/navbar would get messed up, etc.

The slides in question have a really simple format, it's essentially

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Something}
\begin{figure}
\animategraphics[...]{...}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

If anybody could provide an example of the main presentation file and an included slide, along with the necessary commands, that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure if Beamer changes `include`.  In most classes, `include` has a page break before and after the included file.  Otherwise, it behaves exactly as if the contents of the file were dropped in.  In other words, no preamble.  You would then be able to say `\includeonly{}` to not include the graphics when you don't want them.

Comment: @Teepeemm Does it support separate compilation though? I'd really like to have that.